# How to insert a character at specific index of string using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a string entered by the user in the text box. I need to insert char '#' in the string if not entered by the user.

```
expected format : aaa#aa#a
```

Here is the code to verify and correct the expected format:-

if user entered this: aaaaaa,

```
if (enteredtext.Length >= 7 && enteredtext.EndsWith(","))
            {
                if (enteredtext.IndexOf('#', 3, 3) == -1)
                    enteredtext = enteredtext.Insert(3, "#");
                if (enteredtext.IndexOf('#', 6, 6) == -1)
                    enteredtext= enteredtext.Insert(6, "#");
            }
```

Any other best way to achieve it?

Comment: Are the positions for the # known or unknown?

Comment: yes known.. exactly as per the expected format aaa#aa#a

Comment: Then why do you check for "," at the end if it's not in the expected format?

Comment: Patrick... This question is a little part of big features... if could do this then I can easily merge with the whole feature. So , is just an example.. i real its always ending with char 'z'

Comment: btw, this question might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `if (enteredtext.IndexOf('#', 3, 3) == -1)` you can just do:

```
if(enteredtext[3] != '#')
  enteredtext = enteredtext.Insert(3, "#");
```